# CreateMasteringVoice randomly throws HRESULT: 0x88890017

Tags: c++, windows-8, directx-11, xaudio2

```
    m_audioEngine->CreateMasteringVoice(
        &m_masteringVoice,
        XAUDIO2_DEFAULT_CHANNELS,
        sampleRate,
        0,
                    NULL
        )
    );


    m_audioEngine->CreateSourceVoice(
        &implData->sourceVoice,
        format,
        0,
        XAUDIO2_DEFAULT_FREQ_RATIO,
        reinterpret_cast<IXAudio2VoiceCallback*>(&implData->callbackHander),
        nullptr,
        nullptr
        )
    );
```

One of the above code when I have my earphones in seems to always run fine.

If I start my game without earphones in, sometimes (not always) the above function fails. **It always throws the same HRESULT: 0x88890017**

any ideas?

If I put a breakpoint directly after this, it seems to not throw an error... Does this task run asynchronously?

**EDIT---------------------------------**

My IXAudio2SourceVoice keeps getting lost randomly

what can cause that to lose itself?

this is why my program crashes...

it only loses itself when earphones are not plugged in (when creating XAudio2 objects)

Comment: Anyone got any ideas on this so far?

Answer (score 4):

**What does it mean?**

This error code is known as "*AUDCLNT_E_CPUUSAGE_EXCEEDED*" and occurs when the audio engine is taking too long to process audio packets. This typically occurs when the CPU-usage of the audio engine exceeds a certain treshold. The audio engine will fail creating new streams if its CPU-usage exceeds this threshold.

**Resolving: The User**

CPU-usage is subject to various things, like the processing power of your CPU, like the number of channels you're using and like the audio device enhancements you have enabled on a system level. Some possible solutions are to ensure a decent CPU (check the minimum system requirements specification), in the application/game-settings lower the amount of channels in use, or to disable some system-level audio device enhancements in your operating system. For the latter check your task manager for CPU-usage, and if one of the suspicious processes is "audiodg.exe", go into the Sound control panel, double-click each of your playback devices in turn, go to the Enhancements tab, and check the "disable all enhancements" box. This should lower the required CPU-usage and solve your problem.

**Resolving: The Coder**

Keep in mind that the more your audio code is doing, the more CPU-cycles it will require. If you have an IXAudio2 device created with a ton of effect processors in the chain, 1000 SubmixVoices and hundreds of SourceVoices, that's like asking for trouble. Before you point your fingers to the CPU or to the system-level audio device enhancements, do ensure that it isn't just your code being inefficient.

Your big friend here is IXAudio2::GetPerformanceData, which will query the device and fill in a XAUDIO2_PERFORMANCE_DATA-structure for you. This gives you some information about the CPU-cycles used.  Chances are good you can intercept this error before it actually occurs. When you detect a heavy CPU-usage, or when the error actually occurs, it's not necessarily a reason to have things fail in your game/engine/framework. You could retry. Or you could adjust the number of SubmixVoices. Or you could choose to not create a SourceVoice. Or you could temporarily suspend audio/switch to a null-device, and inform the user about all of this.

You could setup an event or callback to inform the user of heavy CPU-usage in the audio engine. This enables the application to inform the user of this heavy CPU-usage, and inform the user to lower the amount of channels in the settings (alternatively you can have your application adjust things automatically) or to turn off some system-level audio device enhancements.

Comment: Gosh, thank you very much! I will try this audio performance stuff... I am guessing I am doing some stupid thing in the code.